# JLabel on top of JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jlabel

No matter what alignment I use, the JLabel is always displayed on the left of my JScrollpane and not on top of it. Here is the code:

```
final JPanel choseTypeOfAnswerText = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Answer:");

label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
choseTypeOfAnswerText.add(label);

//now a scroll pane for the answer area
JScrollPane answerScroller = new JScrollPane(answerArea);
answerScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
answerScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
choseTypeOfAnswerText.add(answerScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//add(answerScroller);
choseTypeOfAnswerText.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Because you are using scrolling container you can't get physical coordinates of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `choseTypeOfAnswerText.add(answerScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);`
- have to change `LayoutManger` to the [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) (`JPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout())`)
- [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) has implemented [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html), corresponding with a.m. described issue
- only [`Top-Level Containers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) have got implemented `BorderLayout` by default

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell, that `label` is supposed to be added in the top area of the panel:

```
choseTypeOfAnswerText.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

And, like mKorbel stated, you have to set the LayoutManager to `BorderLayout`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `JScrollPane` you do not need to put it in a `JPanel`; it actually replaces the JPanel. You can add your label to the `JScrollPane`.

Comment: I have to use JPanel for a curtain functionality of the program